# d3 svg how to center multiple circles

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg, center

i have a json file:

```
{
    "circles": [
        {"name": "Circle", "x":13.284199,"y":-12.223403, "group":1}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":13.277986,"y":-30.081020, "group":0}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":37.270324,"y":-46.266050, "group":0}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":49.085207,"y":-50.323903, "group":1}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":17.334599,"y":-76.113029, "group":1}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":40.067553,"y":-76.576700, "group":0}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":11.616747,"y":-107.550639, "group":0}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":10.827147,"y":-134.892190, "group":0}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":18.657633,"y":-171.319351, "group":0}, 
        {"name": "Circle", "x":50.023818,"y":-182.810422, "group":0}
    ]
}
```

And i am drawing circles and positioning them based on those x and y coordinates.
So far i have tried to set the svg element's `transform="translate()"` to the x and y coordinates of the first circle, but that wasn't successfull.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If the image is what you want, youll have to move the element the circles are appended to. Like so:

```
svg.attr("transform",function(){
                movementX = windowWidth/2 - svgWidth /2;
                movementY = windowHeight/2 - svgHeight /2;
                return "translate("+movementX+","+movementY +")";
                }
                );
```

That's if svg is of type SVG. If not youll have to use offset.

```
$(svg).offset({top : movementY, left: movementX});
```

This will center the svg to the center of the screen. I cant answer it 100% as ill need to see your code and what elements you have used, but the basics are there and should be easily understood.

EDIT

I just realized this wasn't resolved.

I added an ID to the `<g>` tag, i.e the container of the circles and added the following code. I have commented to explain :)

```js
var circleContainer = d3.select('#circleContainer') //get circle container

var circleContainerBBox = getBoundingBox('#circleContainer'); //get bounding box of circle container to get x,y,width and height
var svgBBox = getBoundingBox('#svg'); //same for svg to find offset

var differenceX = circleContainerBBox.x - svgBBox.x - (circleContainerBBox.width / 2); //difference between svg x and circleContainer x take away half the width of the circle container as it draws from top left
var differenceY = circleContainerBBox.y - svgBBox.y - (circleContainerBBox.height / 2); //same for y direction



var width = 800, //set width
  height = 400; //and height

circleContainer.attr('transform', function(d) {
  return "translate(" + ((width / 2) + differenceX) + ',' + ((height / 2) + differenceY) + ')'; //here's were you transform the circle container based on the values calculated above
})


function getBoundingBox(element) { //function to get bbox
  var thisEl = document.querySelector(element)
  var thisElBBox = thisEl.getBBox();
  console.log(thisElBBox)

  return thisElBBox;

}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #00667A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id='svg'>
  <!--Make a javascript script, that sets a transform to the g to center the circles.-->
  <g id='circleContainer'>
    <!-- Transform here <---- -->
    <circle cx="20" cy="10" fill="red" r="10"></circle>
    <circle cx="20" cy="36" fill="red" r="10"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am trying to center the circles in the middle of the svg element, i am not having trouble to position them. The svg's dimensions are 800px X 400px

Comment: one thing to point out, how come you want them all in the center? Surely they'll just over lap and you wont be able to see them all ....

Comment: i don't want the transform on the circles, but on the svg

Comment: Ahhh ok look at my answer in 2 minutes, see if i understand what youre asking

Comment: is that what you want ? if it is, all you do is move the element the circles are appended to. Ill edit again

Comment: i would want to set the transform to the svg itself `<svg transform="(something, something)"></svg>` or `<g transform="(something, something)"></g>`

Comment: put together a fiddle and ill sort it for you

Comment: Hello, are you there?

Comment: @Jojo01 Better late than never, sorry I only got back to you now. Youve probably solved your problem, if not, I have added the answer, if you have, hopefully it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already `transform` these circles by `"translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")`, check if it is because the position y value is negative, and the circle is not visible in your svg area.

Comment: i don't transform the circles i transform the svg

Comment: transform attribute is not applicable on <svg>(but it's okay to use transform on <g>), to change position of svg, I think you need to use 'x' or 'y' attributes (for <svg>)